# Is it true that "setAllValues" works only with one level of the nesting of the form? (By default in React-form)

Tags: reactjs

As I see react-form has a very convenient feature for set all data into form, but only it does not work correctly, when rendering form with '**setAllValues**', all fields must be filled with data, but this does not happen for second and next levels of nesting.

Just for example object with data which I have:

```
const FormData = {
  field1: "field_1",
  fieldsGroup1: {
    field2: "field_2",
    field3: "field_3"
  },
  field4: "field_4",
  fieldsGroup2: {
    field5: "field_5",
    fieldsGroup3: {
      field6: "field_6",
      fieldsGroup4: {
        field7: "field_7"
      }
    }
  },
  field8: "field_8"
};
```

In this topic I would like to make sure that currently 'setAllValues' works only with one level nesting of form by default.

I decided this issue the following way...
I using two component to render form with setting all data to all nested fields 
Please take a look on my example (here ->https://codesandbox.io/s/pjo46r9xnm ) for fully understand my point.

... All seems to work well, but there is a question for the experts, is there another way to fill the form (setting all values from state/store/with other way) with all the nested fields withoout any additional components and use only API react-form, since I didn't found such case in documentation/internet/gitHub of Microsoft)/stackoverflow atc.

or my approch a single way for implementation such case )

Thank you to interest with my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge in addition to react-form

or if it fit to your needs

https://github.com/erikras/redux-form

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. But I mostly interested with react-form, since currently we use this package for our application as a common way. And if use other similar approach maybe it's good idea, but if we can continue work with current library it will be better way for us, since all features which we need, this package all has, but also has issue with 'setAllValues' which make our work slightly not convenient in code implementation.